# How to set unity application version on runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity.Application.version is read-only..

so i tried:

```
UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.BundleVersion = "Text";
```

but PlayerSettings cause build fail

Comment: why would you change the unity version on runtime...? The `UnityEditor` namespace doesn't exist in a build .. you can't use anything from it

Comment: is there any way? never?

Comment: never. This entire namespace is stripped off in a build as it makes no sense there ... a build is a standalone application that has nothing to do with the Unity editor anymore ... What exactly is your goal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant, if u planning to achieve a similar effect like "runtime game update effect" , then your best option is to make the build version as separate variable and track it on your own, or even fetch it from a server api . but really no need to do this. unless its urgent for some reason.